# Error in Django Deployment with Apache centos 7

Tags: python, django, apache

I deployed my application in apache but Getting 500 internal server error due to some issues need assistance to get this resolved

Restarted the service didn't helped me to resolved this.

virtualenvironment name=djangoprojectenv
path=/opt/djangoproject/djangoprojectenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages

projectname - final & Application name - "final_app"
project path - /opt/djangoproject/myproject/final

**Error Log of Apache** (throwing 500 internal server error)

```
[:error] [pid 26320] Traceback (most recent call last):
[:error] [pid 26320]    File "/opt/djangoproject/myproject/final/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[:error] [pid 26320] [application = get_wsgi_application()
[:error] [pid 26320]  File "/opt/djangoproject/djangoprojectenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
[:error] [pid 26320]  django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[:error] [pid 26320]  File "/opt/djangoproject/djangoprojectenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
[:error] [pid 26320]  apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[:error] [pid 26320] File "/opt/djangoproject/djangoprojectenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 78, in populate
[:error] [pid 26320]  raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
[:error] [pid 26320]  RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
```

**WSGI.py** file  [Project name - "final"]

```
"""
WSGI config for final project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "final.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Finally my **/etc/httpd/conf.d/django.conf** as

```
Alias /static /opt/djangoproject/myproject/static
<Directory /opt/djangoproject/myproject/static>
 Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /opt/djangoproject/myproject/final>
<Files wsgi.py>
    Require all granted
 </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess final python-path=/opt/djangoproject/myproject:/opt/djangoproject/djangoprojectenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup final
WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/djangoproject/myproject/final/wsgi.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Missed to install mod_wsgi for corresponding python, though i installed mod_wsgi using below

```
  yum install httpd mod_wsgi -y
```

it needs libraries for running python version. by installing the below package

```
  yum install python36u-mod_wsgi -y
```

Issue got fixed for me. please use corresponding python version and install mod_wsgi libraries for that version as well